# How to look forward with regex and find the end of the desired string?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract reference ids from different strings where the ref id could look quite different. The difficulty I am facing is, how to know when the ref id is finished and the regular text continues.

[Text and regex examples](https://regex101.com/r/cJI6xH/1)

> text Ref. 027/7203.00 more text
>
> -- example 2:
>
> text Ref. 01 733 7720 4055-07 5 21 28FC more text
>
> -- example 3: text Ref. 126281RBR Schoko more text
>
> -- example 4: text Ref. WAY101A.FT6141 More text
>
> -- example 5: Text Ref. 01 774 7699 4134-07 5 22 15FC More text

Regex: 
     **Ref.? ?((?:[A-Z\d./]+)( [A-Z0-9]+)?|(?:[\d.]+))**

The examples 2,5. illustrate the problem of getting the rest of the ref id.

Example 3,4 illustrate the problem of having another word beeing a false positive on the regex. *Schoko* is not part the ref id.

Comment: Your question is good but links tend to have an expiry date. What you could do to make this question better would be to add the examples inline as well.

Answer (score 1):

To match the 2 different formats, you might use a single capturing group with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
Ref\. (\d+(?: \d+){2} \d+-\d+(?: \d+){2} [A-Z0-9]+|[A-Z0-9/.]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `Ref\.` Match Ref.` followed by a space
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\d+(?: \d+){2} \d+-\d+(?: \d+){2} [A-Z0-9]+` Match pattern like `01 733 7720 4055-07 5 21`
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Z0-9/.]+` Match 1+ times any of the character class
- `)` Close capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8SyhSe/1/)

A somewhat more broader pattern could be to repeat 1+ times digits and a hyphen and at the end match the character class `[A-Z0-9/.]+`

```
Ref\. ((?:\d+(?: [\d-]+)+)*[A-Z0-9/.]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d3LTMc/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing this using a negative lookahead with a tempered lazy dot:

```
Ref\.?\s+((?!\s+[^A-Z0-9])[A-Z0-9/. -])*(?= )
```

### Demo

This pattern assumes that reference numbers consist of only numbers and capital letters.  The logic here is to keep consuming so long as what we *don't* see ahead is a space followed by anything *other* than a number or capital letter.  The `(?= )` lookahead at the end also ensures that the pattern stops after matching the very last term in the reference number.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Could you please explain the regex a bit more? The [A-Z0-9/. -] will make sure it will consume aas long as there is no other character?. This pattern is a bit tricky to understand.

Comment: @merlin Have a look [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) for an explanation on how tempered dot works.  I could explain but it still might leave you wondering.